# PHP explode multiple uploaded file into variable

Tags: php, explode

I got a form with multiple upload input, while in the process, I need to separate each in order to update database

```
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){

foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name){

    $file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];

    echo '<pre>'.print_r($_FILES['files'], TRUE).'</pre>';
    }
}
```

let say I have 2 uploaded file, here is data in hierarchical view for these files:

```
Array
(
[name] => Array
    (
        [0] => model8.jpg
        [1] => leslie.jpg
    )

[type] => Array
    (
        [0] => image/jpeg
        [1] => image/jpeg
    )

[tmp_name] => Array
    (
        [0] => C:\xampp\tmp\php906A.tmp
        [1] => C:\xampp\tmp\php906B.tmp
    )

[error] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 0
    )

[size] => Array
    (
        [0] => 13285
        [1] => 45086
    )

)

Array
(
[name] => Array
    (
        [0] => model8.jpg
        [1] => leslie.jpg
    )

[type] => Array
    (
        [0] => image/jpeg
        [1] => image/jpeg
    )

[tmp_name] => Array
    (
        [0] => C:\xampp\tmp\php906A.tmp
        [1] => C:\xampp\tmp\php906B.tmp
    )

[error] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 0
    )

[size] => Array
    (
        [0] => 13285
        [1] => 45086
    )

)
```

How can I set each of the data into a variable for further process?

Thanks!

Comment: since you have multiple files so u can use the while loop that u have and perform the upload operation. Since if you add these in another array you have to again loop and do some operation.

Comment: It's just an array. pull stuff out of it like you would any other array.

Answer (score 2):

Use this PHP function to reorder the $_FILES array:

```
<?php 
    function diverse_array($vector) { 
        $result = array(); 
        foreach($vector as $key1 => $value1){
            foreach($value1 as $key2 => $value2){
                $result[$key2][$key1] = $value2; 
            }
        }
        return $result; 
    } 
?>
```

Initial example $_FILES array:

```
array(1) { 
    ["upload"]=>array(2) { 
        ["name"]=>array(2) { 
            [0]=>string(9)"file0.txt" 
            [1]=>string(9)"file1.txt" 
        } 
        ["type"]=>array(2) { 
            [0]=>string(10)"text/plain" 
            [1]=>string(10)"text/html" 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Reordered example $_FILES array:

```
array(1) { 
    ["upload"]=>array(2) { 
        [0]=>array(2) { 
            ["name"]=>string(9)"file0.txt" 
            ["type"]=>string(10)"text/plain" 
        }, 
        [1]=>array(2) { 
            ["name"]=>string(9)"file1.txt" 
            ["type"]=>string(10)"text/html" 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Use the function like this:

```
<?php $upload = diverse_array($_FILES["upload"]); ?>
```

Now you can access individual uploaded files (any number of them) like this:

```
<?php

    foreach($upload as $file){
        $file_name = $file['name'];
        $file_size = $file['size'];
        $file_tmp = $file['tmp_name'];
        $file_type = $file['type'];
        $file_error = $file['error'];
    }

?>
```